# issue with obtaining user from test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a test for testing the account activation and I'm running into some issues:

```
  test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get new_company_path
    assert_difference 'Company.count', 1 do
      assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
        post companies_path, company: { name: "company",
                                        users_attributes: [{
                                          first_name: 'John',
                                          last_name: 'Doe',
                                          email: 'user@example.com',
                                          password: 'foobar' }]
                                      }
      end
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size

    user = User.last
    assert_not user.activated?
    # Try to log in before activation.
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token")
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid token, wrong email
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template '/'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
```

the issue is that I'm not able to retrieve the user that I've created in the POST. I tried using User.last but that doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have an idea on how to make this work?

Test returns

```
Expected true to be nil or false
```

on line `assert_not is_logged_in?`

Comment: What does the `User.last` returns? And what does the `User.all` returns? (when you call it exactly where you call to `User.last` is located).

Comment: User.all returns : NoMethodError: undefined method `activated?' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f96d3d28a68>
and User.last:
Expected true to be nil or false


However I've checked, and I'm certain the test is 'wrong'